# libvirt / KVM/QEMU - Networks: What does "Open Network" do?

Tags: virtualization, qemu, linux-kvm, libvirt, virt-manager

When setting up a network with libvirt & `virt-manager`, there is an option to choose "Open Network" as the "Network Mode" when forwarding traffic to a physical network.

What does "Open Network" mean / do? I thought it might be the same as an isolated network, but clearly that wouldn't make much sense, as there is a seperate option for that.

See example screenshot below...

[image: libvirt virt-manager open network]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This feature was described when it was added, in the post
[[libvirt] [PATCH 1/3] network: new network forward mode 'open'](https://listman.redhat.com/archives/libvir-list/2016-August/msg00640.html):

> The new forward mode 'open' is just like mode='route', except that no
> firewall rules are added to assure that any traffic does or doesn't
> pass. It is assumed that either they aren't necessary, or they will be
> setup outside the scope of libvirt.

It means that no firewall rules will be automatically added to allow free traffic
on the network.

This is also described in
[libvirt: Network XML format](https://libvirt.org/formatnetwork.html),
section
[Connectivity](https://libvirt.org/formatnetwork.html#elementsConnect)
in a similar manner (more wordy but less clear):

> **open**
>
> As with mode='route', guest network traffic will be forwarded to the
> physical network via the host's IP routing stack, but there will be no
> firewall rules added to either enable or prevent any of this traffic.
> When forward='open' is set, the dev attribute cannot be set (because
> the forward dev is enforced with firewall rules, and the purpose of
> forward='open' is to have a forwarding mode where libvirt doesn't add
> any firewall rules). This mode presumes that the local LAN router has
> suitable routing table entries to return traffic to this host, and
> that some other management system has been used to put in place any
> necessary firewall rules. Although no firewall rules will be added for
> the network, it is of course still possible to add restrictions for
> specific guests using nwfilter rules on the guests' interfaces.) Since
> 2.2.0

Comment: Thanks, if only the UI had the option labelled "Routed (Open Firewall)"

Comment: This is supposedly the option of `mode=route`.

Comment: How does mode="Route" differ from mode="Open", if not the fact that the firewall rules are different?

Comment: Yes, exactly. Isn't this what you asked for?

Comment: Your previous comment confused me - it doesn't matter... If I understood correctly mode=Open is "no firewall rules" and mode=Routed is "some firewall rules may be added"

Comment: Right, that's it.